# Vaadin auto refresh grid data's based on API call in every 30 seconds

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I need to call an API every 30 seconds and need to refresh the grid with updated data. I using Server push, but I can't find the optimal solution in my case. Below is my UI code

```
@Route(value = UserNavigation.ROUTE)
@PreserveOnRefresh
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
public class UserNavigation extends AppLayout {

CCUIConfig config;

    @Autowired
    public UserNavigation( CCUIConfig config) {
    this.config = config;

    addToDrawer(createAccordianMenu());
    }

    private Component createAccordianMenu() {
    VerticalLayout scrollableLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    Div kioskMonitor_div = new Div(kiosksMonitorLabel);
    kioskMonitor_div.addClickListener(event -> {
            try {
                setContent(new Monitor(config).getDashboard());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    scrollableLayout.add(kioskMonitor_div);
    return scrollableLayout;
    }
}


@Push
@Route
public class Monitor extends VerticalLayout{
    

    CCUIConfig config;
    Grid<Model> grid = new Grid<>();
    private FeederThread thread;
    

    public Monitor(CCUIConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
   @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        // Start the data feed thread
        super.onAttach(attachEvent);
        thread = new FeederThread(attachEvent.getUI(),grid);
        thread.start();
    }
   @Override
    protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        thread.interrupt();
        thread = null;
    }

    public  Component getDashboard() throws IOException{
        
        String updateddate =null;

        VerticalLayout dashboardview = new VerticalLayout();
        
        Grid.Column<Model> idColumn = grid.addColumn(Model::getid)
                .setHeader(ID);
        Grid.Column<Model> nameColumn = grid.addColumn(Model::getName)
                .setHeader(Name);
        Grid.Column<Model> memoryColumn = grid.addColumn(Model::getRefreshTime)
                .setHeader(Refresh time"));
        
        dashboardview.add(grid);
        return dashboardview;   
}
}
    


class FeederThread extends Thread {
    private final com.vaadin.flow.component.UI ui;
    private  final  Grid<Model>  grid;
    private final CCUIConfig config;

    private int count = 30;


    public FeederThread(com.vaadin.flow.component.UI ui,Grid<Model> grid) {
        this.config = new CCUIConfig();
        this.ui = ui;
        this.grid= grid;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (count>0){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                ui.access(()-> {
                    System.out.println("Thread Entry ");
                    try {
                    StringBuilder jsongrid = HttpClientGetRequestClient.executeUrlGet(config.getRefreshAPI());
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    List<Model> userlist = new ArrayList<Model>();
                    String date="";
                    if(jsongrid!=null)
                    {
                    ModelWrapper eh = mapper.readValue(jsongrid.toString(), ModelWrapper.class);
                    userlist = eh.getMetricsData();
                    }
                                        
                    if(userlist != null)
                    {
                    grid.setItems(userlist);                
                    grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
                    }
                    }catch(JSONException |JsonProcessingException e) {
                        
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                });
                count--;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

}
```

UserNavigation is the page that loads after user login, it contains a sidebar with multiple options(or functionalities). One of the functionality is the Monitor screen.
Monitor is the page with a grid where we need to refresh it in 30 seconds.
FeederThread is the thread class that calls an API and update the data in the grid asynchronously.

As from the above code, what happens is like

> onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent)

is not getting executed so the grid is not getting displayed on the page,    we use vaadin 14, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should check the https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-push training video about Push. The page has a also exercise project, that is actually answer to your question. There is a Grid that is being updated by background thread.

Comment: You say, that you can't find optimal solution, but you do not state clearly what is actually wrong.

Comment: @TatuLund Thanks for your replay, I have edited my questions with some more details. Now I tried it with push but statements inside onAttach are not getting executed. I tried to add sysout but its not getting printed.

Comment: I recommend you to watch the video carefully and do the exercise task as described there. You have number of issues in your code. As a first hint I would say, you should keep the operation ui.access as atomic as possible. So do not create a new Grid there, just update the items in your grid. Looks like also that you are missing Route annotation in your view.

Comment: @TatuLund I have updated the question and code with more details , still the statements inside onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) is not getting executed

Comment: Please study the exercise project in more detail and pay attention to the patterns used. You are not adding the Monitor component to your view. The Push annotation should be on root layout. You should not instantiate the Grid in thread, as you cannot shared the same Grid instance in multiple UI's.

Comment: @ANONYMUS The Vaadin content is great. It is worth watching the videos. It helped me a lot. Thank you Tatu Lund.